# Trackpad, mouse will not click. Command+Tab switcher is invisible

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, mouse, trackpad, application-switcher

I've had this issue come up about four times now on my 15" retina Macbook Pro, running Mac OS X 10.8.4.

The trackpad will no longer click — neither right nor left click works. Regardless of whether I tap the pad or press the physical click mechanism.

The computer remains responsive via the keyboard and the mouse cursor still moves. However the following symptoms occur:

- Cmd+Space for the Spotlight menu does not work
- Cmd+Tab switches between applications but the visual switcher does not display
- I am able to open apps via the terminal, and force quit them via Cmd+Opt+Esc
- Plugging in an external mouse via USB exhibits the same behaviour (movement only, no response to clicks)

The only thing I've found that resolves this problem is a restart, which I am able to do via the keyboard. I have attempted to kill all open applications but this does not solve the issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I ask because next time this happens I would like to avoid restarting my computer.

Comment: Since you can get to your Terminal, try running: killall Dock

Comment: did you install any third party mouse software (i.e. microsoft intellimouse)?

Comment: I'm having the same issues. did you resolve it?